# If $\frac{\mbox{Tr}(AB)}{\mbox{Tr}(B)} = 1$ for every $B \succeq 0$, then $A=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

> Prove that if $\frac{\mbox{Tr}(AB)}{\mbox{Tr}(B)} = 1$ for every positive semidefinite matrix $B$, then $A$ is the identity.

---

A professor of mine recently used this property in lecture to show that a given matrix is the identity, but this property is not obvious to me.  Could someone show me a proof of this?

The best I could come up with (shared below) is that if $A$ is not the identity, there exists a vector $v$ of unit length such that $v^*Av\neq 1$, so we can define $B = vv^*$, so that $\operatorname{Tr}(B) = 1$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)/Tr(B) = v^*Av \neq 1$, and this proves the statement by proving the contrapositive.

Does this proof require $A$ to be Hermitian? Are there any counterexamples where $A$ is not Hermitian?  I would be grateful if anyone could offer a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Note that the identity is not true for generic $A,B$.

Comment: (take $A$ to be the zero matrix for an easy counterexample)

Comment: @AnyAD Prove that IF Tr(AB)/Tr(B) = 1 for all positive semidefinite Hermitian B, THEN A is the identity.
No one claimed that this is true for all A and B.  It's a conditional statement.
The converse is easily proven, but the forward direction is trickier.
You need to show that if A is not the identity, then there exists some positive semidefinite Hermitian matrix B such that Tr(AB) is not equal to Tr(B).

Comment: This is equivalent to saying $\operatorname{Tr}((A - I)B) = 0$ for all $B$. What if $B = A^* - I$?

Comment: @JWR91 did you modify the statement?

Comment: @AnyAD No. Any edit made after 5 minutes after posting (1 minute before your comment) would have registered in the edit history.

Comment: @JWR91 Is $A$ Hermitian as well?

Answer (score 2):

This answer expands on my comment. It is not necessary for $A$ to be Hermitian.

We note, as I did in my comment, that
$$\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(B) \iff \operatorname{Tr}(AB - B) = 0 \iff \operatorname{Tr}((A - I)B) = 0.$$
If we let $C = A - I$, then we have that $\operatorname{Tr}(CB) = 0$ for all $B$, and we wish to show $C = 0$.

Here's where a little peek at the big picture helps. The fact is,
$$\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(AB^*)$$
forms an inner product on the $n \times n$ complex matrices. So, to say that $\operatorname{Tr}(CB) = 0$ for all $B$, is equivalent to saying $\operatorname{Tr}(CB^*) = 0$ for all $B$, i.e. $\langle C, B \rangle = 0$ for all $B$. This is a classic exercise in the study of inner product spaces: the only such $C$ is $C = 0$. The proof is simple: consider $B = C$. Then $\langle C, C \rangle = 0$, and one of the axioms of inner product spaces implies $C = 0$.

If we don't take it for granted that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product, then we'll need to prove the relevant property: that
$$\operatorname{Tr}(CC^*) = 0 \implies C = 0.$$
By definition,
$$(CC^*)_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^n (C)_{ij}(C^*)_{ji} = (C)_{ij}\overline{(C)}_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n |(C)_{ij}|^2.$$
Thus,
$$\operatorname{Tr}(CC^*) = \sum_{i=1}^n (CC^*)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n |(C)_{ij}|^2.$$
This is a sum of non-negative terms. If $C \neq 0$, i.e. any $(C)_{ij} \neq 0$, then one of the terms will be strictly positive, making $\operatorname{Tr}(CC^*) > 0$. Thus, contrapositively, if $\operatorname{Tr}(CC^*) = 0$, then $C = 0$.

So, given that $\operatorname{Tr}(CB) = 0$ for all $B$, consider $B = C^*$ (which is $A^* - I$, as per my comment). We then get $\operatorname{Tr}(CC^*) = 0$, so $C = 0$, as we just showed. But, since $C = A - I$, this means $A = I$.

Comment: Thank you!  This answer was very helpful!  My only concern is that in order for the proof to work, we have to choose B = A*-I, but we have no guarantee that A*-I is positive semidefinite...

Comment: @JWR91 Oh! How long has that condition been there? My proof doesn't work, in that case. I'm not certain that it is true if $A$ is not Hermitian, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that $A$ is Hermitian. Then, one can write $A-I=\sum_i\lambda_iu_iu_i^*$, where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues and $u_i$'s are the (orthogonal) eigenvectors.

Then we have that

$$\mathrm{trace}((A-I)B)=\sum_i\lambda_iu_i^*Bu_i=0$$

If we assume that $A=I$, then we have that all the $\lambda_i$'s are zero, and the above expression holds for all $B$'s.

To prove the necessity, pick $B=u_ku_k^*$, $k=1,\ldots$. This yields

$$\mathrm{trace}((A-I)B)=\lambda_k=0$$

where we have used the fact that the eigenvectors or orthogonal. This implies that the above expression holds if and only if $\lambda_k=0$. Repeating for all $k$'s then implies that all the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ must be zero and that $A$ must be the identity matrix.

---

Update. In fact, a similar argument can be applied when $A$ is not Hermitian by using the singular value decomposition

$$A-I=\sum_i\sigma_iu_iv_i^*$$

where the matrices $U=[u_1\ \ldots\ u_n]$ and $V=[v_1\ \ldots\ v_n]$ are unitary (i.e. $U^*U=V^*V=I$). This yields

$$\mathrm{trace}((A-I)B)=\sum_i\sigma_iv_i^*Bu_i=0.$$

The rest of the proof follows from the same lines (using now the test matrices $B=v_ku_k^*$ or $B=u_ku_k^*$ for the symmetric PSD case with the extra assumption that $u_k^*v_k\ne0$.) and using the fact that if all the singular values of a matrix are zero, then this matrix must be the zero matrix.

Comment: Can you give any counterexample where A is not Hermitian?
It's sufficient for my purposes to prove it for a Hermitian A, but I think it should work even when A is not Hermitian.

Comment: @JWR91 I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  How do we know that the test matrix (v_k)(u_k)* is positive semidefinite?  What happens if we run into a case where v_k = -u_k?

Comment: @JWR91 You can consider the test matrices $B=u_ku_k^*$ as well with the same result. Nothing happens when $v_k=-u_k$.

Comment: If we use the test matrices B = (u_k)(u_k)*, then we get (σ_k)(v_k)*(u_k) = 0 for all k, but if v_k and u_k are orthogonal, then we have have (v_k)*(u_k) = 0, so we have no guarantee that σ_k = 0.

Comment: @JWR91 Please write your math in math format for readability. But you are right, in this specific case, that would not work but it may be possible to adapt that by choosing an arbitrary set of positive definite matrices for $B=B_j$, $j=1,\ldots$ so that the matrix $[M]_{ij} = v_i^*B_ju_i$ is invertible. It might even be possible to construct this family explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice "physics-y" way to prove this.
If A is NOT the identity, then there must exist some vector v of unit length such that the inner product v*Av =/= 1.

We can then use this vector v to construct the matrix B = vv*, which we know to be Hermitian and positive semidefinite, since it is just a projection onto v.

Since trace is invariant under change of basis, we have Tr(B) = v*v = 1.

We also have, by the same logic, Tr(AB) = v*Av =/= 1, and thus Tr(AB)/Tr(B) =/= 1.

Therefore, if A is not the identity, there exists a positive semidefinite Hermitian matrix B such that Tr(AB)/Tr(B) =/= 1.

The contrapositive of this statement proves the theorem: If Tr(AB)/Tr(B) = 1 for every positive semidefinite matrix B, then A must be the identity. QED

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: But what is a “physics-y” way to prove that $A\ne I\Rightarrow\exists v,\,v^\ast v=1,\,v^\ast Av\ne1$?

Answer (score 1):

Another (equivalent) view as the one in @TheoBendit's answer but using rotational property of the trace : If $\mathrm{Tr}(CB)=0$ for all $B$, then for any $i$ and $j$

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Tr}(Ce_ie_j^T)&=\mathrm{Tr}(e_j^T C e_i)\\
&=e_j^T C e_i
\end{align*}
therefore $C=0$.